# MySQL mass insert acting weird

Tags: java, mysql

I'm working with MySQL to upload around 10000 entries into the database. Here is my code:

```
public void addChests(HashMap<Location, ChestGeneratorType> map) {

    java.sql.PreparedStatement statement;
    try {
        statement = plugin.sql.openConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO chests (Location, Generator, ToAdd) VALUES (?,?,?)");

        for (Location l : map.keySet()) {
            map.get(l).chests.add(new Chests(l, map.get(l), 0));

            statement.setString(1, Utils.locationToString(l));
            statement.setString(2, map.get(l).configName);
            statement.setInt(3, 0);

            statement.addBatch();
        }

        statement.executeBatch();
    } catch (SQLException sqlE) {
        sqlE.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This piece of code should be going through my map and inserting a new row for each value in the map. The map has around 10000 entries, and I tested that by dumping the map into a text file, one per line, and I got 9800+ entries. So I know my HashMap is full. But what is happening is it's only putting in 1513 entries, not 9800+. And whats weird is in all those entries, the "generator" value is "irongenerator". It's only inserting it if the ChestGeneratorType.configName is irongenerator? Why?

MySQL database: https://gyazo.com/5a0686a48a6238d2d958f7a7411696b2

Better explaination(I'm working in a bukkit plugin): https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/mysql-mass-insert-acting-weird.99373/

Thanks

Comment: Print out the contents of the map each loop iteration, check what it says. Print out the size of the map at the beginning of the method, just to make sure you're giving it the right input. Add a third catch block for just Exception, so you can catch an Exception that you didn't think could occur.

Comment: This is a dump of the map: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104089738/dumps/dataDump.txt
Just ctrl+f and type in Location to count the maps, should be around 9800.  And I added the exception catch and still nothing. @EricGuan

Comment: If I get the size of the map.keySet(), it returns around 9800...

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right database? You insert with `ToAdd = 0`, but your linked image shows a value of `6`.

Comment: Yes I am sure. There is another part of the code which increments that value on a repeating task, which is why it's more than 0 in that picture. @EricGuan

Comment: So, there is other (undisplayed) code running, that manipulates this table. Are you sure that other code is not deleting those records? Try running *this* method **and nothing else**. You should then get 9800+ records, all with a `ToAdd` value of `0`. If that works, your problem is elsewhere, which would then be why you can't find the error *here*.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue..

I had another task which would TRUNCATE the table to then insert the values again. It would TRUNCATE the table right after I inserted all the irongenerators, which explains why the column generator were all the same..

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a constraint (`FOREIGN KEY` or `CHECK`) on the `Generator` column, or your other values are too long for the `VARCHAR` type, or the values are null and `Generator` is `NOT NULL`.

This is causing some of the `INSERT` statements to fail, but [`executeBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29) is allowed to continue (feature since Java 1.3), and will execute all the statements, *then* throw a [`BatchUpdateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/BatchUpdateException.html) (subclass of `SQLException`).

The [`BatchUpdateException.getUpdateCounts()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/BatchUpdateException.html#getUpdateCounts%28%29) method can then be called to get an `int[]`, and iterating that array will let you know which statements failed (value `EXECUTE_FAILED`).

But, you catch that exception, call `printStackTrace()` (you should have seen this), and then (**OH HORROR!**) continue normally, allowing `addChests()` to return normally, and all the successful inserts are committed. **OOPS!**

---

*Unrelated*

You are calling `map.get(l)` **3** times inside the loop. Very inefficient. Either assign to variable, or, better yet, iterate the map entries, not the keys:

```
for (Map.Entry<Location, ChestGeneratorType>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Location           loc  = entry.getKey();
    ChestGeneratorType type = entry.getValue();
    type.chests.add(new Chests(loc, type, 0));
```

Comment: For the Generator Column I am using tinytext.... And I don't get any errors in my console... I put in a BatchUpdateException and it didn't catch.

Comment: Then, for the sake of testing, run them one at a time (replace `addBatch` with `executeUpdate` and remove `executeBatch`), and print return value.

Comment: I did this, http://hastebin.com/oqicoqunor.avrasm, which I call for each value I have(using this method: http://hastebin.com/gidijabeba.avrasm). The count value outputs 9800+ so I know that the addNewChest method is being ran that many times. Still the same result, 1513 entries. And I don't know what you mean by print return value.

Comment: I ran this query(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104089738/dumps/mysqlDump.txt) using MySQL workbench to my database and it works perfectly. So obviously my table setup is fine. There is just some very odd issue in my code... Hmm...

Comment: The Array of Int's that you get from statement.executeBatch() is outputting 9857 1's. Doesn't this mean it should all be there?